# How to format date from database in Yii2

Tags: php, date, internationalization, formatter, yii2-basic-app

If I have function like this

```html
protected function getAreaValues($model)
 {
  return 
  [
   [
    $model->getAttributeLabel('EXPDATE'),TbArea::findOne($model->KODE)->EXPDATE
   ], 

  ];
 }
```

where EXPDATE IS date data

How to format it in d-M-Y ?

I add formatter in web.php in config like this

```html
  'formatter' => [
   'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
   'nullDisplay' => '-',
   'dateFormat' => 'd-M-Y',
   'datetimeFormat' => 'd-M-Y H:i:s',
   'timeFormat' => 'H:i:s',   
  ],
```

But still not working

Answer (score 1):

You can format date like below.

```
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('2017-03-30', 'd-M-Y'); // 30-Mar-2017
```

try this.

and you can check Yii2 doc

[Yii2 Formatters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatting.html#configuring-formatter)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
$DateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $yourOldDateString);
$newDateString = $DateTime->format('d/M/Y');
```